# Setting custom hotkeys

Tags: c#, hotkeys

```
    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) == -32767)
        {
            timer2.Start();
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LControlKey) == -32767)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I use this for hot keys but is there a way for me to have a set button so a user could pick and set his own hotkey in the program instead of using a preset one.

Comment: what did you try? some links to start research: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Shortcut-HotKey-Editor-5b4c6560, https://gist.github.com/rzhw/1470282

Comment: Thanks for this looks like this will help out

Comment: I advice you to use a key press event or global key event hook (depending on what you need) instead of a timer